# Rank columns MySQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to rank my columns. (Column 1, column2) and add an overallRank. But I have no idea how to do this. See table 1 and 2 for my example. Table 1 is the current situation and I would like to go to table 2. So I calculate the ranks and store them in my new table.

I’d like to rank Column1 high -> low, Column2 low -> high. For the overallRANK I would like to combine the column ranks with different weights.  1 * Colomn1RANK + 2 * Colomn1RANK low -> high.

Is this even possible, if so, how?

[image]

Comment: There is no magical SQL solution that is going to always keep you columns ranked and you overall rank calculated.  To me, you would be looking at a scripted solution to make these updates.

Comment: [similar question from the stack][1]


  [1]: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97184/how-do-i-rank-the-total-score-in-order-of-positions/97187#97187

read carefully both solutions provided

Answer (score 1):

You can add the rank using variables.  In this case, you need to do it twice:

```
select t.*,
       (col1rank + 2 * col2rank) as overallrank
from (select t.*, (@rn2 := @rn2 + 1) as col2rank
      from (select t.*, (@rn1 := @rn1 + 1) as col1rank
            from table t cross join
                 (select @rn1 := 0) vars
            order by col1 desc
           ) t cross join
           (select @rn2 := 0) vars
      order by col2 asc
     ) t;
```

It is unclear whether `overallrank` is just a combination of the two ranks, or whether you want another rank on top of it.  If the latter, then it is just another `order by` and ranking variable in the outer query.

Comment: set the variables before using them. Surround them in transaction